# AndroidViewModel onChanged() function is not working in another activity?

Tags: android

I am creating a chatting app and I have 2 main activities. One for showing Contacts and on for Messages. Now in my Contacts Activity I am using following code to populate my recyclerView.

```
contactsViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory
                .getInstance(this.getApplication())).get(ChatViewModel.class);

 contactsViewModel.getAllUsers().observe(this, new Observer<List<UserContacts>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<UserContacts> userContacts) {
                contactAdapter.submitList(userContacts);
                if(!userContacts.isEmpty())
                {
                    userList = userContacts;
                }

            }
        });
```

This is working good and UI is populated. Now when user click on the contact my Message activity starts and I need to get some information about user so I am using the same above code like this inside Message Activity.

```
chatViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this,ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(this.getApplication())).get(ChatViewModel.class);
    
chatViewModel.getAllUsers().observe(this, new Observer<List<UserContacts>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(List<UserContacts> userContacts) {
                    Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Inside", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    for(int i = 1; i <= userContacts.size();i++)
                    {
                        UserContacts user = userContacts.get(i);
                        if(user.getId() == id)
                        {
                            reciever = user.getFriend();
                            profile = user.getPicture();
                            firstName = user.getFirstName();
                            lastName = user.getLastName();
                            friendPublicKeyString = user.getFriendPublicKey();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

But this time this function is setting values to null. I have tried debugging and the thread of contact Activity goes inside the function but Message Activity thread does not go inside and values are assigned null (As shown in images).

[debugging of contact Activity function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIMFV.png)

[debugging of Message Activity function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mstN7.png)

When viewModel is intialized inside the constructor allContact is initialized with chatRepository

```
public ChatViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        chatRepository = new ChatRepository(application);
        allContacts = chatRepository.getAllContacts();
        oneChat = chatRepository.getOneChat();
        allChatsJustForId = chatRepository.getAllChatsJustForId();
    }
```

ViewModel returns allContacts through.

```
public LiveData<List<UserContacts>> getAllUsers()
    {
        return allContacts;
    }
```

chatRepository constructor initilize all contacts from userContactsDao

```
public ChatRepository(Application application)
    {
        ChatDatabase db = ChatDatabase.getInstance(application);
        chatDao = db.chatDao();

        userContactsDao = db.userContactsDao();
        allContacts = userContactsDao.getAllContacts();

        senderHelperDao = db.senderHelperDao();

        oneChat = senderHelperDao.getOneChat();

        allChatsJustForId = chatDao.getAllChatJustSoICanSeeMaxPrimaryKey();
    }
```

ChatRepository returns allContacts through

```
public LiveData<List<UserContacts>> getAllContacts()
    {
        return allContacts;
    }
```

contactDao looks like this

```
  @Query("SELECT * FROM UserContacts ORDER BY priority DESC")
    LiveData<List<UserContacts>> getAllContacts();
```

Comment: Can you show the code where the viewmodel pulls the actual users list?

Comment: @TwoHorses i has pasted the code. Also i have confirmed that the query is working in Dao

Comment: Have you debugged the whole second `onChanged` method. Your current picture shows you debugging before you've assigned any values, which would explain why they're null.

Comment: @HenryTwist no its not before its after. The thread skipped the function and now is at the next line.

Comment: Ah I see sorry! So the toast line doesn't get reached at all?

Comment: @HenryTwist Yes it does not reach there.

Comment: @HenryTwist the problem is that this function is working fine in previous activity and here it doing nothing. Im thinking it has to do with the fact that im initializing same viewModel in next activity

Comment: That's really strange, the view model wouldn't be the same instance as they have different scopes.